# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/mips/libRSSupport.so' when using buildToolsVersion 28.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

I have update my **buildToolsVersion** from 27.0.3 to **28.0.1**. When i compile my project, i have compile error:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/mips/libRSSupport.so'
```

When i click on **Build->Run build**, i see this:

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.    
...  
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:49)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)  
...  
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)  
...  
Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/mips/libRSSupport.so'
    at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$acceptOnlyOne$2(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:75)
    at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$select$3(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:100)
    at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMergerOutputs$1.create(IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java:86)
    at com.android.builder.merge.DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.create(DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.java:61)
```

How to fix this error? Or is it bug of Google Build Tools?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A temporary solution is to add this to your build.gradle (app level) inside `android {}`

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude "lib/mips/libRSSupport.so"
    exclude "lib/mips/librsjni.so"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. But, what is the libsjni.so? And why problem with this lib?

Comment: I don't know what it is but after excluding `libRSSupport.so`, it was the next thing that raised an OS independent exception. So excluding it was the next logical step I had

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I have found the solution, I have added this to the build.gradle(module) :

```
andrid{
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "**/lib/**"
    }
}
```